# Deploy PowerBuilder application

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I'm trying to deploy the examples project that comes with PowerBuilder 9 IDE to an .exe file.

1. Full build - passed successfully.
2. Deploy - fails with the following error:

   "The current library list is different than the library list contained within this project. The project library list has been updated. specify build options for the updated list and try again."

How can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

By the time you've seen this message, PowerBuilder has updated your library list in the project (assuming you've got the project open in the project painter). Just hit Deploy again to start the build. Remember to hit Save before you close the painter, or else you'll go through the same dance next time.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: This is the correct answer so perhaps someone will update it as correct. If there are libraries not in the list, PB will display that error and add the missing library in the list though you will need to look at the checkbox in library list, if you create PBD's than you'd need to click the checkbox for newly added library.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these 8 simple steps :

1. Open the system tree (toolbar)
2. Right click your project and then choose **"New..."**
3. In the "New" dialog, click on **Project tab** and choose **"Application Wizard"**
4. In the first step **"Specify Destination Library"**, just click "Next"
5. In the others step, change what you need and click "Next"
6. In the last step, of course, click "Finish". Your are done
7. You now see 2 projects in the System Tree(You can delete the old one right click/Delete
8. Deploy the new one

Answer (score 0):

Delete your (application) project file and create a new one. The new project will be created with an up-to-date list of libraries

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of pbl in the Library search path. For that, look at the properties of your target objet.

The list must match with the PB list in your object Projet.

If not edit source of the objet projet by hands (right clic edit source).